# Is there a way to disable image hotlinking by 3rd-party sites while allowing Google Image Search

Tags: bing, bandwidth, google-image-search, hotlinking

Can I block other sites from hotlinking to images on my server to preserver bandwidth while still allowing my site to stay discoverable in Google and Bing image search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming Apache and .htaccess.

From: https://perishablepress.com/creating-the-ultimate-htaccess-anti-hotlinking-strategy/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$           [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^https?://([^.]+\.)?domain\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^https?://([^.]+\.)?google\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^http?://([^.]+\.)?google\.  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^https?://([^.]+\.)?bing\.   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^http?://([^.]+\.)?bing\.    [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$                             - [F,NC,L]
```

You will need to change *domain* in the HTTP_REFERER line to your domain name of course. You may also want to change https to http as well. Also, you can add and or delete file extensions. They do not all have to be images.

This is a trusted site for .htaccess examples should you ever need one.

Comment: Hi closetnoc, please see my comment on Mike's answer

Comment: You would also need to specifically allow hot linking from google.com and bing.com because the hot link images in search results.

Comment: @KnocksX This does allow indexing, however, to be sure that there is no trouble, you can add a referrer per search engine you want. I will add Google and Bing examples.

Comment: @KnocksX - I deleted my post because I just saw your question was updated and my rules caused your images to not to be indexed by google.

Comment: @Mike I understand why you deleted your answer- I would like to say that sometimes another point of view or idea is important even if it does not directly address the question. This is because sometimes there is good advice in taking another tact. I liked your tact in preventing scrapers. It shows that you are thinking from another perspective. Please keep this in mind because sometimes understandings are too one dimensional. BTW- I like your answers!! You are a breath of fresh air! Keep chucking in ideas- Please.

Comment: lol I will keep going. I'm sure I posted elsewhere on here a similar set of rules to prevent scrapers but the OP is strongly interested in having images indexed with google.

Comment: @Mike I have an idea that I will ask on the meta site where we can see if there are other answers that should be wiki answers (not sure how all this works). It may be time to do a mini audit and see if there are topics that could be wiki topics and whether there is a good question for it or not. If no good question exists, perhaps we can create one and collaborate on solid answers as a group each user throwing solid answers. I had you in mind for this! You give great answers and I know that we can come up with good questions and answers with you involved. Cheers!!

Comment: Its too bad my primary job isn't in this field or I'd be having more of a blast

Comment: @Mike I understand. I am semi-retired from the IT industry. I am a landlord, property manager, sometimes property renovator, micro-farmer, antiques dealer, etc. I can afford to be here at at odd times chucking in, but sometimes I do have to run-away for hours at a time. That is why I tend to be here in the middle of the day and evenings. I take care of morning business, come here, take care of afternoon business, come back, take care of evening business, come back again at night. Sometimes I am gone most all day. But I am here everyday because as you said it- it is a blast!!

Comment: Thank you guys.  I have used the code above, and it seems to be working so far.  Expect more .htaccess questions from me soon. :)

Comment: @KnocksX Anytime!! Let me know if you have any problems. I can adjust the code if you need me to. We are here to help. Heck I am largely retired from the IT industry and cannot walk away entirely... doing some research and having fun here. I would not be surprised if I die at the keyboard- so if you see a bunch of odd characters, please call an ambulance! ;-)